# java get date marker field(am/pm)

Tags: java

I need to get the field AM/PM in date object. How can i get it?

This is my code.

```
String startTime ="01:05 PM";
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

 Date st = sdf.parse(startTime);
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use a [`Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(st);
if (cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM) {
  ...
}
```

Make sure you don't have a time zone mismatch when you do this.

Comment: @cletus hi will you update your code ?? because now it gives error in android studio.

Answer (score 8):

Calendar is probably best, but you could use DateFormat, too:

```
String amPm = new SimpleDateFormat("aa").format(time);
```

The TimeZone caveat also applies here.

Answer (score 3):

[`Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) can also do

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(st);
String meridiem = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault())
```

`meridiem` now equals "PM" based on your code.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss_aa");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Log.d("Time", ""+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    int day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    System.out.println("time => " + namesOfDays[day-1]+"_"+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 2):

use this..

```
String getTime(String milliseconds) {

    String time = "";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(milliseconds));

    time = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + " : " + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if(cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==0)
        time=time+" AM";
    else
        time=time+" PM";

    return time;

}
```