# Format android.text.format.Time with AM/PM

Tags: android

I am working with the deprecated (*since version 22*) android.text.format.Time.
Right now I need to know if my time is AM or PM.

> I understand that this class is deprecated since SDK >= 22 but I need to get this working with the class android.text.format.Time since I can't switch to Gregorian calendar in this code

I am using this code, which is not working:

```
Time time = new Time();
time.clear("my timezone");
time.setToNow();
```

The code is working but when I try to get the AM/PM symbol with this:

```
String symbol = time.format("aa");
```

I get back

```
> aa
```

Comment: Tried, not working. It prints "a"

Comment: use calender for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323964/java-get-date-marker-fieldam-pm

Comment: Found it, you need to work with Linux format
http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

In this case time.format("%k") and it works